Unable to process files from S3 in SNOWFLAKE PROC
Needed some help in creating the below PROC. my goal is to copy the latest todays data from s3 files and load into tables. Few error handling i have added, like when file is not present then it would add it into log table, when file is present but load into table failed, i have marked entry in log, when its success the same has been added into log table. But its unable to do so. I am facing error while calling the proc.
I think this portion might be the issue as it might not be able to get the count even if file is present:(needed some help with this)
file_count_1 := (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE(
FUNCTION('LIST', '@@DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.S3_SF_DEV/Test/FILE/DATA', { PATTERN => dynamic_file_pattern })
)
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_DATA_TO_RAW()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
DECLARE
  dynamic_file_pattern VARCHAR;
  dynamic_file_pattern_1 VARCHAR;
  copy_command VARCHAR;
  copy_command_1 VARCHAR;
  file_count_1 INTEGER;
  file_count_2 INTEGER;
BEGIN

  -- Construct the dynamic file patterns
  dynamic_file_pattern := '.*EQ_TEM_TST' || TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYYMMDD') || 'T.*[.]csv';
  dynamic_file_pattern_1 := '.*EQ_TST' || TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYYMMDD') || 'T.*[.]csv';

  -- Check if files exist using LIST command
  file_count_1 := (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE(
      FUNCTION('LIST', '@@DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.S3_SF_DEV/Test/FILE/DATA', { PATTERN => dynamic_file_pattern })
    )
  );

  file_count_2 := (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE(
      FUNCTION('LIST', '@@DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.S3_SF_DEV/Test/FILE/DATA', { PATTERN => dynamic_file_pattern_1 })
    )
  );


  -- If any file is not found, log the error and stop execution
  IF (file_count_1 = 0 OR file_count_2 = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE (TABLE_NAME, STATUS, DATE_MODIFIED)
    VALUES ('TABLE1', 'Latest files not found.', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    RETURN 'Latest files not found.';
  END IF;

  -- Truncate tables before loading data
  TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE1;
  TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE2;

  -- Construct the COPY INTO command dynamically for TABLE1
  copy_command := '
    COPY INTO TABLE1 (
      INTERNAL, NAME, DESCRIPTION, START, ACTION, CLASS, VISIBILITY, ATTRIBUTES, ACATTRIBUTES
    )
    FROM (
      SELECT
        t.$1 AS INTERNAL,
        t.$2 AS NAME,
        t.$3 AS DESCRIPTION,
        t.$4 AS START,
        CASE
          WHEN t.$5 = ''Create'' THEN 1
          WHEN t.$5 = ''Modify'' THEN 2
          WHEN t.$5 = ''Delete'' THEN 3
        END AS ACTION,
        t.$6 AS CLASS,
        t.$7 AS VISIBILITY,
        t.$8 AS ATTRIBUTES,
        t.$9 AS ACATTRIBUTES
      FROM @@DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.S3_SF_DEV/Test/FILE/DATA
      (PATTERN => ''' || dynamic_file_pattern || ''') AS t
    )
    FILE_FORMAT = (
      TYPE = ''CSV'',
      COMPRESSION = ''NONE'',
      SKIP_HEADER = 1,
      FIELD_DELIMITER = ''|'',
      FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = ''"''
    )
  ';
  -- Construct the COPY INTO command dynamically for TABLE2
  copy_command_1 := '
    COPY INTO TABLE2 (
      INTERNAL, NAME, DESC, ORG, EQUTN, ISEQUA, ACTIVE, FILTER, ATTRIBUTES, ACATTRIBUTES
    )
    FROM (
      SELECT
        t.$1 AS INTERNAL,
        t.$2 AS NAME,
        IFF(t.$3 = '''', ''<NULL>'', t.$3) AS DESC,
        t.$4 AS ORG,
        t.$5 AS EQUTN,
        CASE WHEN t.$6 = ''YES'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ISEQUA,
        CASE WHEN t.$7 = ''YES'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ACTIVE,
        t.$8 AS FILTER,
        t.$9 AS ATTRIBUTES,
        t.$10 AS ACATTRIBUTES
      FROM @@DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.S3_SF_DEV/Test/FILE/DATA
      (PATTERN => ''' || dynamic_file_pattern_1 || ''') AS t
    )
    FILE_FORMAT = (
      TYPE = ''CSV'',
      COMPRESSION = ''NONE'',
      SKIP_HEADER = 1,
      FIELD_DELIMITER = ''|'',
      FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = ''"''
    )
  ';

  -- Try loading data, and handle any failures
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE copy_command;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE copy_command_1;

    INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE (TABLE_NAME, STATUS, DATE_MODIFIED)
    VALUES ('TABLE1', 'SUCCESS', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHER THEN
    INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE (TABLE_NAME, STATUS, DATE_MODIFIED)
    VALUES ('TABLE1', 'LOAD FAILED', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    RETURN 'LOAD FAILED';
  END;

  RETURN 'LOAD COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY';
END;
$$;```



so you have defined external stages right? Why don't you try something like, i don't know if it works but is more like some select to s3 files that we query,
SELECT count(*)
FROM @[EXTERNAL_STAGE_NAME]/[TABLE or whatever you define as the access to the files]/S3_SF_DEV/Test/FILE/DATA (file_format => [if you define a file format], PATTERN => :dynamic_file_pattern);


I am just curious  about Function call from this Select . I have never seen like this you calling List System function inside Table Function . Ideally it should be you first execute LIST function and then  use RESULTSCAN function to get the result of last executed query. Something like this . LIST  @DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.S3_SF_DEV/Test/FILE/DATA and then use TABLE FUNCTION to process resultscan result TABLE(RESULTSCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))

Hello, i don't get why you are talking of using last_query_id when @Jeet Chatterjee stated only that: "my goal is to copy the latest todays data from s3 files and load into tables". So if the guy has external stages that i'm assuming that he has cause isn't another way of integration between snowflake and AWS, he could use a simple select statement from List function and use the pattern to obtain the latest data, or maybe i'm not understanding the request.
